# How to set the value of a read-only property with generic getters and setters?

Tags: c#, properties

Not sure if I worded this correctly ... but I have the following code:

```
    public Guid ItemId
    {
        get;
    }

    public TransactionItem()
    {
        this.ItemId = Guid.Empty;
    }
```

Naturally I am getting a read-only issue ... which I do understand.  Is there anyway to set this property value without having to do something like the below:

```
    Guid _itemId = Guid.Empty;
    public Guid ItemId
    {
        get
        {
            return _itemId;
        }
        set
        {
            _itemId = value;
        }
    }
```

or

```
    public Guid ItemId
    {
        get;
        internal set;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I would go for this:

```
public Guid ItemId
{
    get;
    private set; // can omit as of C# 6 
}

public TransactionItem()
{
    this.ItemId = Guid.Empty;
}
```

Of course, it would be open for setting within this class, but since you are writing it I hope you have the sense to not break your own intentions...

In my opinion, things like readonly properties, are mostly important when seen from the outside. From the inside, it doesn't really matter what it is, cause there, you are the King =)

Comment: +1 a lot of people don't realise props can have different scopes

Comment: This looks like the way I am going to go! Thank you! Was more or less curious to see if it could be done without having a "set".

Comment: opening the door of a house without a door is pretty difficult... :p

Comment: This seems to be the way to do it.  I wish they actually had a `readonly set;` in addition to `private set;`.  The difference would be that the property could only be set in constructors allowing immutability to be enforced throughout the rest of the class.

Comment: @DavidPeterson I think actually something like readonly set may come in the next version of C#. Another alternative is of course to have a readonly private field and then just have only a get property.

Comment: @Svish, I hope they do.  That would be wonderful!  I have no idea why it never occurred to me to have a read-only field and a get-only property.  Sadly, that is much more verbose than a read-only set, but it does solve the mutability problem.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4):

If you just need the `ItemId` property to be read-only for external users of your class, then Svish's answer is the way to go.

If you need `ItemId` to be read-only within the class itself then you'll need to do something like this:

```
private readonly Guid _ItemId
public Guid ItemId
{
    get { return _ItemId; }
}

public TransactionItem()
{
    _ItemId = Guid.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [readonly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) keyword

```
public readonly Guid ItemId;

public TransactionItem()
{
    this.ItemId = Guid.Empty;
}
```

Comment: @Jakub, Making your fields non-private is something you shouldn't do unless you *absolutely* need to: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid your question isn't very clear - but if there isn't a property setter defined, then you certainly can't call it.

Are you *actually* after an automatically implemented read-only property, allowing setting just within the constructor? If so, I'm afraid that's not available, much as I'd like it.

Just to expand on what I mean, I'd *like* to be able to do:

```
// Not valid in C# - yet!
public class Foo
{
    // Autogenerated field would be readonly in IL.
    public string Name { get; readonly set; }

    public Foo (string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public void Bar()
    {
        // This would be invalid
        this.Name = "No!";
    }
}
```

Basically it would be "make a property like a readonly field."

Comment: I didn't think I worded it correctly ... but what you are saying is correct. Just trying to save some typing ... and was curious on top of it.

Comment: No problem. I've edit the answer to show what I'd like to be able to do - I believe it's what you want too.

Answer (score 0):

Use a private setter, or set the backing field ?
(But, then you must make sure that the name of your backing field can be determined based on the property-name.
For instance by making sure that your backing field always has the same name as the property-name, but is prefixed with an underscore; like `NHibernate` does it using its access-strategies).